# How to use one click event handler for multiple buttons

Tags: jquery

I have 4 buttons with different id's. When i click on them i need to perform one function. So i need something like this:

```
$('#button #button').click(function()
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To select the 4 buttons at once you write the following:

```
$('#button1, #button2, #button3, #button4').click(function(event){ /* code here */ });
```

If you need to identify which button was pressed, write something like:

```
$('#button1, #button2, #button3, #button4').click(function(event){ 
    if($(event.target).attr('id')=='button1'){
        /* specific code for button1 */
    } else if($(event.target).attr('id')=='button2'){
        /* specific code for button2 */
    } else if($(event.target).attr('id')=='button3'){
        /* specific code for button3 */
    } else if($(event.target).attr('id')=='button4'){
        /* specific code for button4 */
    } 
});
```

Comment: I don't see the point in using one callback if you have different codes.

Comment: Me neither... Anyway, the question is not that clear either ... :-)

Comment: @P.R.Ribeiro how to identify the which button is clicked if there is only one button under a repeater?

Comment: @Akansha I did not understand your question.

Answer (score 9):

Easiest would be to add a class to all your buttons like so:

```
$('.button_action').click(function()
```

Comment: What if different buttons need different classes?

Comment: @Lijo you can create a new class with no styling that all the buttons can share. Also, you can apply multiple classes to an element.

Answer (score 2):

Use a comma :

```
$('#button1, #button2').click(function()...
```

Answer (score 0):

Separate each `id` with a comma:

```
$('#button1, #button2, #button3, #button4').click(...)
```