# How could I combine Javascript functions created by a loop in the code behind in to one function so I don't have to repeat?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe

How do you run through variables in jquery to link with a foreach query in php?

I have a page with a number of images which are place holders for iframes. When you click on the rsPlayBtn div the image is replaced with an iframe. The only way i can think to do it to increment the id & class ($counter) and then make a jquery function for each. This seems like a very inefficient way of doing i, also the number of images/iframes will be variable so with this method I have to create a load of variables that will not be used every time. How could I combine what I have done in to one function so I don't have to repeat?

```
echo "<div class='rsBtnCenterer' id='{$counter}'><div class='rsPlayBtn'>.";
echo "<img class='{$counter}'..."; 

--------

$('#1').click(function(){
var video = '<iframe src="'+ $('.1').attr('data-video') +'"></iframe>';
$('#1').hide();
$('.1').replaceWith(video);
});

$('#4').click(function(){
var video = '<iframe src="'+ $('.4').attr('data-video') +'"></iframe>';
$('#4').hide();
$('.4').replaceWith(video);
});
```

Comment: You say that 'there obviously must be a better way to do it'. Try to phrase what should be improved and what problem you run into when making that improvement. Asking for improvement is too broad.

Comment: thank you, I have slightly updated the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985642/how-to-use-one-click-event-handler-for-multiple-buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really clear to me what your problem is. I'm assuming the last is what your question is about:

**How could I combine what I have done in to one function so I don't have to repeat?**

It seems to me you are using class and id inefficiently.

```
echo "<div class='rsPlayBtn' id='{$counter}_btn'>";
echo "<img id='{$counter}_img'..."; 


$('.rsPlayBtn').click(function(event){
  var counter = event.target.id.substring(0,1);
  var video = '<iframe src="'+ $("#" + counter + "_img").attr('data-video') +'"></iframe>';
  $("#" + counter + "_btn").hide();
  $("#" + counter + "_img").replaceWith(video);
});
```

Like this you don't need to create separate functions for every button. All buttons are found by jQuery using the "rsPlayBtn" class. You get the counter using the event.target property. the rest is the same code as you have, with the inserted counter.

Also you should avoid using the class property if you want to target a single element. Always use the id property for that, it is much faster. This part is bad practice, see how i changed it?:

```
echo "<img class='{$counter}'...";
```

Comment: Thank you - that has got to the point of what I am trying to do. I have tried out but it doesn't seem to work unfortunately.

Comment: If you post some error messages or other useful information I or others can help you more.

Comment: There was an error but it was one i made. I have created a jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/0c16dLaq/ (which also doesn't work) to try and figure it out. thanks for your help

Comment: Do you know how to debug javascript? It's really simple. Simply add [debugger;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) as a line of code somewhere in your code, and the browser will automatically hit the breakpoint there when the debugger window is open. You open a debugger window by pressing F12 in your browser. Once the F12 window stops at the debugger code, you can step through the code and look at the values of the variables. I made a mistake, and I already found it, I'll post it in an hour, see if you can find it on your own till then. : )

Comment: it is coming up as undefined src for the iframe - why that is i have no idea

Comment: The error was that I used the ID, instead of the counter. The id value is "1_btn", so when looking for the _img, it was looking for "#1_btn_img", which of course doesn't exist (undefined). I had to truncate the _btn using substring(0,1), leaving only the counter. Then it works. Practice the debugging, it's one of the most important skills for development : )

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense - I couldn't see that in the debugger (which i will use more). i need to look up substring, my jquery/javascript knowledge is very rudimentary. Thanks again for your time and help.