# How to use one event handler for two objects, if event occurred for both?

Tags: jquery

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985642/how-to-use-one-click-event-handler-for-multiple-buttons) helped me clear the picture about one event for two objects.But how can I start the function only if event occurred for both objects? (so if only for one object - function won't trigger)

For examlpe: if both of input fields are filled.

Thank you for attention

Comment: Please post relevant code in the question itself. Questions should be self contained and we shouldn't have to follow a link trail to review what your basic issue is. See [ask]

Answer (score 0):

For two input's required to be filled simply check inside the event handler:

```
var $inputs = $('#input-1, #input-2').change(function(){
    // `this` is element event occurred on
    if(  $(this).val() && $inputs.not(this).val() ){
       // code when both filled

    }else{
       alert('Missing a value')
    }
});
```